#  How can I get gcc to find certain libraries?

Tags: files, g++

I am trying to compile a program (gcc, using some functions from intel's ipp library). 
It is my first use of ipp, so I think I might be doing some not very clever mistake. Anyhow:

```
g++ -o inteltrial inteltrial.cpp -I/home/me/Desktop/work/p1/geqw4/vi3/out/sp/ccode/eigen -I/opt/intel/composerxe/ipp/include -L/opt/intel/composerxe/ipp/lib/intel64/ -libipps_l.a -libipps_t.a
```

gives:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -libipps_l.a
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -libipps_t.a
```

now, `-libipps_l.a` `-libipps_t.a` are in `/opt/intel/ipp/lib/intel64`

How to point gccto the right location?

**EDIT:**

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712558/intel-performance-primitive-ipp-installation) seems to be related, but I can't find on the internet how 
to add a line to ld.so.conf....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this did the trick:

```
IPPROOT=/opt/intel/ipp
export IPPROOT
cd /home/me/Desktop/work/p1/geqw4/vi3/out/sp/ccode
icpc -O3 -o inteltrial inteltrial.cpp -I/home/me/Desktop/work/p1/geqw4/vi3/out/sp/ccode/eigen -I$IPPROOT/include -L$IPPROOT/lib/intel64 -lipps -lippcore
```

Answer (score 1):

What the error you see is saying is that the program `ld` cannot find those files.  The `/usr/bin/ld:` part identifies what is throwing the error, not where the checks for the files are occurring.

Comment: ok thanks.....now, how to show gcc where those files are?

Comment: @user2413 I am not familiar with how to fix the gcc compiler's options, so don't mark my answer as the correct answer.  I would recommend that you amend your question to say "How can I get the system to find the files?", and just leave this answer as a "This was helpful to explain the error" answer.